How do you verify xpath or css selector in firefox?
IN the long before time, I used fire-path plugin in firefox to verify if my selector would find all the elements that I needed for selenium tests, but I cannot figure out how to do this in the current firefox development tools. and yes I have looked but didn't' find the answer that I was looking for. Everything I find is over 5 years ago and doesn't address Firefox Developer tools. Inspecting a specific elements paths or css is easy, but then how do you get the list of elements?

On console: $x('//some/xpath') will get list of elements found by that expression

Duplicate of How to find xpath of an element in firefox inspector for XPath and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2208790/215552 for CSS. Please search a little before asking (the first was found using site: stackoverflow.com verify xpath in firefox, the latter using site: stackoverflow.com verify css selector in firefox, pretty much identical to your title

For XPath you can use
$x("xpath")

and for CSS selectors you can use
$$("css selector")

For more so called Web Console Helpers, see the docs.
